# AngularJS Filter table based on radio button combine with textbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm  new to angularjs here i want to achieve when i click one radio button the textbox should filter the table by specific column. when i click another radiobutton  the textbox should filter the table by another column.For Example when i click "sficode" radiobtn the textbox filter the table based on sficode column and when i click Title/description it should filter according to that column "Desc".

```
<div style="width:250px;margin-left: 9px;">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend style="color: #424248;margin-bottom:        0px;">Search</legend>
                            <input type="radio" name="Search" id="rdoSfiCode"                    value="SfiCode" ng-model="filters.x">
                            <label for="rdoSfiCode">SfiCode</label>
                            <input type="radio" style="margin-left:5px;" name="Search" id="rdoTitleDisc" value="TitleDisc" ng-model="filters.y">
                            <label for="rdoTitleDisc">Tile/Discription</label><br>
                            <input type="text" style=" width: 200px;height:     25px;" id="txtSfiorDisc" ng-model="search" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
        <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="corrItem in CorrItems">
                    <td >{{corrItem.SfiCode}}</td>
                    <td>{{corrItem.Tile/Discription}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is my json data:

```
 $scope.CorrItems=[{"SFICode":"803.025.01","Desc":"Repair coupling of the discharge pump of the Bilge Water Separator"},{"SFICode":"823.125.01","Desc":"pump of the Bilge Water Separator"},]
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/l6owYp2sKkcllbFrof1Z?p=preview

```
 <input type="radio" name="filter" value="SFICode" ng-model="filter" ng-change="clearFilter()">
 <label for="rdoSfiCode">SfiCode</label>

 <input type="radio" name="filter" value="Desc" ng-model="filter" ng-change="clearFilter()">
 <label for="rdoTitleDisc">Tile/Discription</label>


 <input type="text" ng-model="search[filter]" />


<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | filter:search">
    <td>{{value.SFICode}}</td>
    <td>{{value.Desc}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And your angular code:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    SFICode: "803.025.01",
    Desc: "Repair coupling of the discharge pump of the Bilge Water Separator"
  }, {
    SFICode: "823.125.01",
    Desc: "pump of the Bilge Water Separator"
  }];

  $scope.clearFilter = function() {
    $scope.search = {};
  }
});
```

Some general advice, be consistent with capital letters and collect your style attributes in a css file!

Arrays in Angular shouldn't start with a capital letter (CorrItems -> corrItems), neither should object properties (SFICode -> sfiCode) etc.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote part of your code. Now ng-repeat in table looks like

```
<tr ng-repeat="corrItem in CorrItems|filter: searchText">
 <td >{{corrItem.SFICode}}</td>
 <td>{{corrItem.Desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

and `searchText` filter is defined on the above form part as follows:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend>Search</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="Search" id="rdoSfiCode" value="SFICode" ng-model="radioValue">
  <label for="rdoSfiCode">SfiCode</label>
  <input type="radio" name="Search" id="rdoTitleDisc" value="Desc" ng-model="radioValue">
  <label for="rdoTitleDisc">Title/Discription</label><br>
  <input ng-model="searchText[radioValue]" ng-init="searchText = {}; radioValue='SFICode'" type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

you could probably clean your code more, anyway sticking with your original code I created [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ue2Ltsas/) you can try.